# sectionInset not working with UICollectionView estimatedItemSize in iOS8 using AutoLayout

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I can't get my UICollection to properly set `sectionInset.left` margin when using self-sizing cells with `estimatedItemSize`. Cells of the UICollectionview should have a somewhat fixed cell height but dynamic width according to the text length.

Here is how it looks when the self-sizing is enabled:

[image]

And when the self-sizing is disabled:

[image]

Oddly enough, it seems that `sectionInset.right` is working, i.e. the margin is added on the right hand side of the UICollectionView.

Here's my custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout, i'm toggling self-size mode using the comment.

```
class myFlow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

        self.minimumLineSpacing = 1
//        self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 35)
        self.sectionInset.left = 20
    }
```

And my custom UICollectionView:

```
class myCV: UICollectionView {
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

    }
}
```

I've laid out the label inside the UICollectionView cell using AutoLayout:

[image]

Comment: I tested this again with XCode 7 beta 1 and it's working with that release so i assume it's a bug in Apple's current implementation of self-sizing cells for UICollectionView. Another issue i had was about getting random out of bounds exceptions with index references like `9223372036854775806` which i traced down to be caused by `estimatedItemSize` as well.

Comment: I just met a very similar bug. The left inset was reported to the right inset for a view really similar to yours ( UiCollectionView, horizontal mode) when I use estimatedItemSize.

Comment: I have the same problem but for all insets. My problem is a bit worst because I need to set different content sizes to different sections. And actually, the collection view doesn't even display itself if I set the content inset to be different than 0,0,0,0. Even if 1, 0, 0, 0...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around this - use `contentInset` property of `UIScrollView`, that is super class of `UICollectionView`. It is not strictly saying is answer, but, at least, a solution of the problem